# Olympus Camera Kitによる傾きの取得

Tags: android, olympus-camerakit

[Olympus Camera Kit](https://opc.olympus-imaging.com/sdkdocs/index.html)経由で傾き(roll, pitch)を取得しようとしています。Android版の[OAModeDial](http://app.olympus-imaging.com/oamodedial/ja/)を見ると水準器の表示は微妙な角度の変化に追随しています。

CAMERA KITを使ったアプリでは、カメラの傾きが変化するにつれて`onUpdateStatus()`が`LevelGauge`で呼ばれるのだろうと思うのですが、コードを書いて動かしてみると得られたmapから`orientation`で引いた値（`landscape`とか`portrait_left`とか）が変化した場合にしか、角度の通知が行われません。そのような仕様なのでしょうか。

なお、`onUpdateStatus()`が呼ばれない場合、例えば`onUpdateLiveView()`から `getLevelGauge()`を呼んでみても、角度値は更新されていないようで、角度を得る方法がありません。

コードは以下のような感じです。

```
void onUpdateStatus(OLYCamera camera, final String name) {
...
 } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("LevelGauge")) {
      updateAngles();
 } ...

private void updateAngles() {
....
  Map<String, Object> map = camera.getLevelGauge();
  if (map != null) {
     Float rolling = (Float)map.get(OLYCamera.LEVEL_GAUGE_ROLLING_KEY );
     Float pitching = (Float)map.get(OLYCamera.LEVEL_GAUGE_PITCHING_KEY);
  }
....
```

Answer (score 3):

OPCサポートです。

ご質問ありがとうございます。
Camera Kitを調査しましたところ、不具合があることが判明いたしました。 大変失礼いたしました。

アップデート版を公開予定ですので、もうしばらくお待ちください。

(2015.10.08追記)
大変お待たせいたしました。
ver. 1.1.1にて対応いたしました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ver. 1.1.1での対応を確認いたしました。ありがとうございます。

ただ、今度は角度の変化がない（ように見える）場合でも、どんどん通知が行われるようになりました。温度や電源電圧などの要因により、加速度センサーから得られる値が微妙に変化しているためと思います。特に弊害はないと思いますが。